# Does data.table dcast() drop 'data.table' attribute?

Tags: r, data.table

it seems dcast() returns a data.frame although the input argument is a data.table:

```
d  <- data.table(id = c(1,2,3), group = c('a','a','b'), x = c(10,20,30))
dc <- dcast(d, id ~ group, value.var = 'x')

> class(d)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> class(dc)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Is there a way to make dcast() return a data.table?

```
> sessionInfo('data.table')
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

attached base packages:
character(0)

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.6
```

---

Comment: Hmm, can't reproduce. `data.table_1.9.6` same as you. (R 3.3.1; linux). Maybe an update thing?? You have a `data.table::dcast.data.table`, right?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `reshape2` loaded too? Does `dc <- data.table::dcast(d, id ~ group, value.var = 'x')` work? Please share `sessionInfo()`. In general, you don't need the `reshape2` package at all when using `data.table` as it imported/improved all of it's (useful) functions.

Comment: Sorry guys. With a freshly started session it works as expected and when I load reshape2 it does indeed return a data.frame. I had just wrongly assumed that when the tooltip (in Architect; when hovering over the function in my script) shows the help for dcast.data.table that it would also execute this function, but that is apparently not the case. So, sorry for the question and lesson learned.

Comment: In that case, you may want to self-answer for anyone else that might arrive to the same problem. Especially helpful would be explaining your debugging process.